# Download dynamic webpage with login details using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to download dynamic webpage using python, the website is created from script.

unfortunately the webpage is downloaded without any content, any idea what I am doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

The code is

```
import xlrd
import requests
import time
import sys


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def open_file(path):

    """
    Open and read an Excel file
    """

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

    USERNAME = ""
    PASSWORD = ""
    sURLbase = "https://example.com/Orders/OrderDetail/"
    sloginURL = "https://connect.example.com"

    session = requests.session()

    login_data = {
        "action": "login",
        "USERNAME" : "username",
        "PASSWORD" : "password"
    }

    r = session.post(sloginURL, data=login_data)
    print("Login Response: ", r)

    time.sleep(5)

    for s in workbook.sheets():

        if s.name == "2014":

            for row in range(s.nrows):

                value  = s.cell(row,5).value

                if(value != ""):
                    if(value != "Order"):
                        try :
                            value = str(int(value))
                        except :
                            pass

                        sURL = (sURLbase + value)

                        print(sURL)

                        r = session.get(sURL)

                        while (r.status_code != 200):
                            print("Login")
                            r = session.get(sURL)
                            r = session.post(sloginURL, data=login_data)


                        print("Fetch Response: ", r)

                        sFileName = value + ".htm"
                        with open (sFileName, "w") as fh:
                            fh.writelines(r.text)



#----------------------------------------------------------------------


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\company\\company.xlsx"
    open_file(path)strong text
```